# Get HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse in Spring Security 4

Tags: spring, security, servlets, request, response

I've tried inject HttpRequest, HttpResponse.

Tried

```
@Bean
public RequestContextListener requestContextListener(){
   return new RequestContextListener();
}

@Controller("/test")
 public class Test {
    public String callback() {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        HttpServletRequest request = attributes.getRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response = attributes.getResponse();
    }
}
```

Nothing, I always receive an empty object.

Comment: `public String callback(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {...}`. This has nothing to do with Spring Security it is basic Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the Spring way to do it:

```
@Controller("/test")
 public class Test {
    public String callback(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        ...
    }
}
```